# ServerAlias not working in ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, ubuntu-12.04

I know it is a question asked several times, but I've read them all and not solved the problem.
I have configured the virtualhost apache like this:

**sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.loc**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.loc
ServerAlias www.example.loc

DocumentRoot /var/www/example/web
<Directory /var/www/example/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
```

I put this in /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   example.loc
```

and then I loaded the site in this way:

```
sudo a2ensite example.loc
```

and restarted apache.

If I go on example.loc working properly, but if I go on www.example.loc does not work, saying that it is impossible to find www.example.loc!

I have done something wrong in the configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is becuase `www.example.loc` is a different FQDN than `example.loc` is, and you haven't specified the former in your hosts file.

Just make the line of your hosts file look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   example.loc www.example.loc
```

Comment: Thank you!
So it works!
But there is a problem with the use of the sessions.
In fact, if you are logged on example.loc, if I go to www.example.loc are not logged in!
it is as if I went on two different sites!

Comment: Well that's a software development problem, not a systems administration problem.